# Get last row with specific value in column, Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have

df = pd.DataFrame('data', car, 'ok')

df:

```
 data               car         ok                                                       
2020-03-25           A            
2020-04-01           A           x
2020-04-15           A              
2020-05-08           A           x
2020-06-25           A           x
2020-06-27           A
2020-07-15
```

I want to select last (old in this case) row being column 'ok' with "x"

I want to obtain

```
2020-04-01   A     x
```

Thanks!

Comment: sorry old case is : 2020-04-01           A           x

Comment: Is your data sorted by date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) method on [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) can give you the first `n` rows of a `DataFrame`. [Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) of a DataFrame will allow you to select rows meeting your filter criteria - to narrow to a subset `DataFrame` with such rows. Together, you could use them to do:

```
r = df.loc[df.ok == 'x', :].head(1)
```

What you are doing here is narrowing to a subset `DataFrame` where `ok` is `'x'` (the `df.loc[df.ok == 'x', :]` part), then taking the first row of it (the `.head(1)` part). This of course assumes the `DataFrame` is sorted by date as it is above.

Indexing is a huge and fundamental topic (think of it as the SQL `WHERE` of pandas) so you should spend time gaining a deep knowledge of it. Here is a [great tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-index-explained-b131beaf6f7b). [This one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_indexing_and_selecting_data.htm) and [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-and-selecting-data-with-pandas/) are also good.

Answer (score 1):

This will work also when your data is not sorted:

```
df[df.ok == 'x'][df.data == df.data.min()]
```